# what should the ending condition of spiral matrix print be?

Tags: java, matrix, spiral

I have written code to print a matrix spirally.

I am correct with my traversals, but I'm not able to come up with the ending condition of the number of layers in the matrix.

Please see my code below

I get the expected output when I hardcode the number of layers to 2, since I know the matrix beforehand. How can I replace the condition in the while loop with something so it would work for all matrices.

```
public class IterativeSpiral
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[][] a = {
                {'a','b','c','d'},
                {'l','m','n','e'},
                {'k','p','o','f'},
                {'j','i','h','g'}
        };

        fun(a,4,4);
    }

    static void fun(char[][] a, int rows, int cols)
    {
        int count = 0;

        //this condition in while loop needs to be replaced
        while(count < 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Layer"+count);

            for(int i = count;i<cols-count;i++)
                System.out.print(a[count][i]);

            for(int i = count+1;i<rows-count;i++)
                System.out.print(a[i][cols-count-1]);

            for(int i = cols-count-2;i>=count;i--)
                System.out.print(a[rows-count-1][i]);

            for(int i = rows-count-2;i>count;i--)
                System.out.print(a[i][count]);

            count++;
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

**My attempts at finding an ending condition**

1. Any ending condition I think of, I keep hitting a counter example
   where it doesn't work like 2*5 (more columns), or a 5*2(more rows)
   matrix.
2. The only ending condition I can think of, is to count the number of
   elements after each for loop and break from the while loop when it equals rows*cols. Howevere, I do not want to do this. I am looking for an ending condition with something using the variables in code.

Comment: I think you should keep track of staring / ending row index, and also starting / ending column index.  Once a staring index overlaps with ending index you can terminate.

Comment: you could think of each iteration as operating on a smaller and smaller matrix. Here iteration 1 would be the outline of a 4x4, iteration 2 would be the outline of a 2x2, iteration 3 would be the outline of a 0x0. Eventually you would either have a 0xM/Nx0 - in which case you `end` or a 1xM/Nx1 in which case you would `print` the last row/column and then `end`

Comment: @mixmastered, thanks. But I would like my program to be general and not just for a square matrix. I'm not sure the above works in that case?

Comment: @PepperBoy for non-square matrix, it reduces to either a 0x0 (`end`) or a Row/Column Vector. For a Row/Column Vector, you can still do half a "matrix" spiral interation to print out the vector and then `end` (You can still go along and down, but a vector isn't thick enough for you to then come back and up)

Answer (score 0):

When the matrix is wider than it is tall, the number of rows determines the end condition. When it is taller than it is wide it's the number of columns.

The number of layers will be half the number of rows or columns, rounding up.

So the termination condition is

```
while(count < (Math.min(rows, cols) + 1) / 2)
```

However, you also need to add some extra conditions inside the loop for the 3rd and 4th runs to prevent outputting repeating elements because there won't be an exact number of layers when min of the number or rows of columns is odd:

```
if(count != rows-count-1)
{
    for(int i = cols-count-2;i>=count;i--)
        System.out.print(a[rows-count-1][i]);
}

if(count != cols-count-1)
{
    for(int i = rows-count-2;i>count;i--)
        System.out.print(a[i][count]);
}
```

Of course you could also use some of the other termination conditions, but hopefully this answers your question given that you said you don't want to use those.

Comment: Edited answer, it's not possible to do it with a while loop condition only because there won't always be an exact number of layers, you also need to have if conditions inside the loop.